# How do I retrieve echo each fam_mamber value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

on a previous page, the value 'numberOffamembers' is inputted by the user which creates user inputs for the names of each family member. I want to then store these names in a database. So to test, I tried to echo the fam_member[] values when the next buttons are clicked but it keeps saying that fam_member[x] is an unidentified index.

```
<?php 
include('db_connect.php');
if (isset($_POST["prev"])) {
    //echo "prev has been clicked";
    header("location: page4.php");
}
if(isset($_POST["next"])){
$fam_member = $_POST['fam_member[1]'];
echo $fam_member;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Add_extra_bio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="script.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to the Abundant Grace Fellowship</h2>
    <p>===================================================</p>
<form action="page5.php" method = "POST">
 <?php
    for($x=1;$x<=$_GET['numberOffamembers'];$x++){
    ?>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Family Member <?=$x?>:</td>
          <td><textarea tabindex="2" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="fam_member[<?=$x?>]" rows="1" cols="50" method="post"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobile Number if any:</td>
          <td><textarea tabindex="2" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="phone_no[<?=$x?>]" rows="1" cols="50" method="post"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><hr width="1150px"></td></tr>
      </table>
    <?php
    }
?>
</form>
<?php
?>
  <form action="page5.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="prev" value="Prev">
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already tried

```
echo $_POST['fam_member[1]'];
```

or changing the index

```
$x = 1
echo $_POST[fam_member[$x]];
```

The Previous page's code:

```
<?php 
include('db_connect.php');
//Previous button. Included on every page except 1
if (isset($_POST["prev"])) {
  header("location:page3.php");
}
if (isset($_POST["next"])){
  header("location:page5.php"); 
    $numb = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['numberOffamembers']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(Number of Additional Family Members) VALUES($numb)";
}

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Select_extra_num</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="script.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to the Abundant Grace Fellowship</h2>
    <p>===================================================</p>
  <p>Select number of extra family members from the dropdown list below</p>
<form action='page5.php'>
   <select name="numberOffamembers" id="famMembers">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10+</option>
   </select>
  <br>
<input type="submit" name="next" value="next">
</form>
<form action='page3.php'>
    <input type="submit" name="prev" value="prev">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am still a novice at php and this page was created by someone else.

Comment: whats your controller? I see the data being submitted but not the controller who will send that data to the next php file. you do have a controller for that, right?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0):

for *echo $fam_member* value dont add [1]

```
$fam_member = $_POST['fam_member[1]']; **<-----this is wrong**
```

**follow this to echo :**

```
$fam_member = $_POST['fam_member'];  <----- this is right
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to your problem. The problem here is that you are submitting the below `form` but the `textarea` fields are present in the upper `form`, that's why you not getting the textarea values in your POST request.

**Step 1:**
Move the buttons to the upper `form` element, just below the `for` loop ending bracket.

**Step 2:**
You are using the wrong `name` for your `textarea` fields. You don't have to print index inside the name attribute. It will automatically assign the index to id. Change it from this:

```
name="fam_member[<?=$x?>]"
```

To this:

```
name="fam_member[]"
```

You are also getting the values in wrong manner through `$_POST`. So, change this line:

```
$fam_member = $_POST['fam_member[1]'];
```

To this:

```
$fam_member = $_POST['fam_member'];
echo $fam_member[0];
```

**Below is the complete working example for page 5:**

```
<?php 
include('db_connect.php');
if (isset($_POST["prev"])) {
    echo "prev has been clicked";
    header("location: page4.php");
}
if(isset($_POST["next"])){
    $fam_member = $_POST['fam_member'];
    echo $fam_member[0];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Add_extra_bio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="script.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to the Abundant Grace Fellowship</h2>
    <p>===================================================</p>
<form action="page5.php" method = "POST">
 <?php
    for($x=1;$x<=$_GET['numberOffamembers'];$x++){
    ?>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Family Member <?=$x?>:</td>
          <td><textarea tabindex="2" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="fam_member[]" rows="1" cols="50" method="post"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobile Number if any:</td>
          <td><textarea tabindex="2" id="message" class="input-xxlarge" name="phone_no[]" rows="1" cols="50" method="post"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><hr width="1150px"></td></tr>
      </table>
    <?php
    }
?>
    <input type="submit" name="prev" value="Prev">
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next">
</form>
<?php
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope that will help!